# primefaces update panel from p:autoComplete

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have the p;autocomplete tag as below which populates list of contacts

```
<h:form id="relationshipsForm">
//code
    <p:autoComplete id="contactAutoComplete"
                                rendered="#{relationshipController.relationshipsName=='Contact'}"
                                value="#{relationshipController.contactKeyWord}"
                                completeMethod="#{contactRelationshipController.completeContacts}"
                                var="contact" itemLabel="#{contact.fullName}"
                                itemValue="#{contact}" converter="#{contactConverter}"
                                forceSelection="true" size="35" scrollHeight="200"
                                panelStyle="width:10px;">
                                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="relationshipsForm,graphViewPanel" />
                            </p:autoComplete>
```

On selecting the contact it should ajaxically update the below tab view

```
<p:outputPanel id="graphViewPanel">
                <h:inputHidden id="orgViewUnMappedJSonDataList"
                    value="${relationshipController.getOrgViewUnMappedJSonData()}" />
                <h:inputHidden id="orgViewMappedJSonDataList"
                    value="${relationshipController.getOrgViewMappedJSonData()}" />

    <p:tabView scrollable="true" id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="true">
                    <p:tab id="orgViewTab" title="Org View">
                        <h:outputScript library="js" name="go.js" />
                        <h:outputScript library="js" name="gojs_org_view.js" />
                        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="gojs_org_view.css" />
                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `<p:outputPanel  id="graphView">` alter for `<div id="graphView">`.

In fact, `<p:outputPanel` render in clientside a `div` tag.

Comment: I changed the div to <p:outputPanel id="graphViewPanel"> and I changed p:ajax as <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="relationshipsForm,warningDialog,graphViewPanel" /> but still the panel is not refreshing @RongNK

Comment: @RanPaul You try to change `rendered="#{relationshipController.relationshipsName=='Contact'}"` to `rendered="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the id of the tabview to the list of component id's to update of the ajax within the autocompelte.

Comment: I changed the div to <p:outputPanel id="graphViewPanel"> and I changed p:ajax as <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="relationshipsForm,warningDialog,graphViewPanel" /> but still the panel is not refreshing @djmj

Comment: Is the outputpanel also a child of the `NamingContainer` `h:form`? If not you need to use the full qualified id-path. Your question does not holds this information.

Comment: Yes the outputpanel also a child of the NamingContainer h:form,i changed it to <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="relationshipsForm:graphViewPanel" /> and also am using a button <p:commandButton value="Visualize"       update="relationshipsForm:graphViewPanel" /> to refresh the panel but its not getting refreshed

Answer (score 1):

Why do you update your autocomplete itself on selecting a value? You should update the other content, where you wish to display your information. AsRongNK said, use p:outputPanel with an id or h:outputPanel with an id to update.

You can reference the id from the p:ajax then.

Comment: I changed the div to <p:outputPanel id="graphViewPanel"> and I changed p:ajax as <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="relationshipsForm,warningDialog,graphViewPanel" /> but still the panel is not refreshing @anm